# PHP Inserting Form Data from a prepopulated dropdown menu

Tags: php, database, post, dropdown

I have a form where the user fills out input boxes and dropdown menus. I have two menus: faculty and departments which the selections are pre-populated from a database for the user to select from. The code I am using for the boxes with manually added "select" options works fine, but does not work for the prepopulated ones.

```html
//Code to populate the faculty dropdown. 
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT fName, lName FROM Faculty order by lName" );
Faculty Member (If Applicable)
<select>
  <option selected="selected">- Select -</option>
  <?php
  foreach( $result as $value )
  { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $value->fName; ?>"><?php echo $value->fName.' '.$value->lName; ?> 
 </option>
  }
</select>
```

```html
//How I'm saving the other inputs, department and faculty will not work using this. 
$activity = $_POST['activity_Name'];
     $cont_Name = $_POST['cont_Name'];
     $cont_phone = $_POST['cont_phone'];
     $cont_email = $_POST['cont_email'];
     $faculty_ID = 30;  //hard-coded for now b/c dropdown box selection not working 
     $course_ID = $_POST['course_ID'];
     //$category_ID = $category previously defined above 
     //$age_ID = $age previously defined above
     $dept_ID = 1;  //same for this one 
     $Start_Date = $_POST['start_date'];
     $End_Date = $_POST['end_date'];
     $location = $_POST['Location'];
     $URL = $_POST['URL'];
     
     
     $wpdb->insert('Activity', array('activity_ID' => 'null', 
                   'activity_Name' => $activity, 
                    'cont_Name' => $cont_Name,
                    'cont_phone' => $cont_phone,
                    'cont_email' => $cont_email,
                    'faculty_ID' => $faculty_ID, 
                    'course_ID' => $course_ID,
                    'category_ID' => $category,
                    'age_ID' => $age,
                    'dept_ID' => $dept_ID,
                    'Start_Date' => $Start_Date,
                    'End_Date' => $End_Date,
                    'Location' => $location,
                    'URL' => $URL));
     
 //Activity Title
 echo("Activity Title: " . $activity . "<br />\n");
 
 //Contact Name 
 echo("Contact Name: " . $cont_Name . "<br />\n");
 
 //Contact Email
 echo("Contact Email: " . $cont_email . "<br />\n");
 
 //Contact Phone 
 echo("Contact Phone: " . $cont_phone . "<br />\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
```

First of all, your select doesn't have a name, so no value from select will be sent with form.

```
<option value="<?php echo $value->fName; ?>"><?php echo $value->fName.' '.$value->lName; ?>
```

And you are assigning fName to option value, but you expected faculty ID. I think you want to assign faculty ID to option value instead.

```
<option value="<?php echo $value->faculty_ID; ?>"><?php echo $value->fName.' '.$value->lName; ?>
```